# How do I auto-fill excel Table data range to right dynamically using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write VBA code for auto-filling excel Table range data dynamically to Right side column wise as per given date.
For eg. If I give Date for "Sep-19" in Worksheet it should automatically auto-fill the table range to right containing Sept-19 data. I am using Excel 2016 version.
Below is the table data:

[image]

I have tried some code, below is the vba code for it:

```
Sub Macro4()

Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Month]]").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillRight
Range("Table1[[#All],[Aug-19]:[Sep-19]]").Select

End Sub
```

I want the `Range("Table1[[#All],[Aug-19]:[Sep-19]]").Select` in last of code to be set up dynamic as per given month, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and desired output? I don't think it's quite clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I want to find the last used column and just drag the table column to the right dynamically. for eg. Above table data contain data till month of Aug-19, I want vba  code which will drag/auto-fill data to right (add one column to right containing Sep-19 data). I have set formula in rows.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will select the dynamic range of the column and first 6 rows starting from A1

```
Sub rg()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Data")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(LastCol).Copy
Columns(LastCol + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Angad, Thanks for your code, but I want to auto-fill the table to right inserting a new column every month, can you please help me in this?

Comment: @Vish-Please refer the updated column, hope it will serve your purpose

Comment: Thanks Angad, for this code but every time it selecting & copying column 1 and pasting value in column 2.  I want to copy last column and paste value after it, can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, finally I got the solution for my problem, below is the code for it.

```
Sub Macro4()

    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Month]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("N3").Value


End Sub
```